# store.loadData() not working in Extjs 6

Tags: extjs, store, extjs3, extjs6

I am upgrading from `extjs3.2.0` to `extjs6`

I have a store as follows-

**mainStore format**

```
data
    0
       0   some value
       1   some othervalue
       2   and so on

    1
       0   some value
       1   some othervalue
       2   and so on
mappings
    0   id
    1   name
    2   address
```

I have used following code to load this data into another store and it works fine

```
var addressStore = stores.newstore;
addressStore.loadData(mainStore);
```

Both addressStore and stores.newstore are filled with following data

**stores.newstore**

```
data
    items
        0
             data
                id       somevalue
                name     some othervalue
                address  and so on
        1
             data
                id       somevalue
                name     some othervalue
                address  and so on
```

Now while upgrading, this code doesn't work. `Loaddata()` do not loads data into newstore.
I also tried using `loadRawData()` and `store.model`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Post a fiddle, there's no point asking why code doesn't work without being able to see the relevant code.